# How can I unite multiple objects to add their keys?

Tags: javascript

Implement the `sumObjects` function, which takes an unlimited number of objects and returns an object that combines all the objects entered.

**Notes:**

> All object properties will have numeric values only
> If the object keys match, the values of the corresponding keys are summed
> The function always returns an object
> The numbers in the object can be positive or negative
> You can use the rest operator to collect arguments passed to a function in one array

**Examples:**

```
const obj = {};
sumObjects() === {}
sumObjects(obj) === {}
```

and

```
const first = {a: 2, b: 4};
const second = {a: 2, b: 10};
const third = {d: -5};

sumObjects(first) === {a: 2, b: 4}
sumObjects(first, third) === {a: 2, b: 4, d: -5}
sumObjects(first, second, third) === {a: 4, b: 14, d: -5}
```

This is my code.

```
function sumObjects(...params) {
  
  let C = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(params[0])
        .concat(Object.keys(params[1]))
        .map(k => [k,
            (params[0][k] || 0) + (params[1][k])
        ])
  )

  return C
}
```

I don't know how to add all these objects into one.
The bottom line is that I need to combine all the objects, but I just don't know how to do this, I can't find anything.

Comment: Looks like concat just doesn't remove duplicates so duplicates keys are processed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the param objects using `.reduce` and for each object, set/update its properties in `acc`:

```js
function sumObjects(...params) {
  return params.reduce((acc,item) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([property,value]) => {
      const prev = acc[property];
      acc[property] = prev ? prev+value : value;
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const first = { a: 2, b: 4 };
const second = { a: 2, b: 10 };
const third = { d: -5 };

console.log( sumObjects(first) );
console.log( sumObjects(first, third) );
console.log( sumObjects(first, second, third) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array of objects and iterate the entries of a single object.

```js
const
    sumObjects = (...objects) => objects.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = (r[k] ||0) + v);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    first = { a: 2, b: 4 },
    second = { a: 2, b: 10 },
    third = { d: -5 };

console.log(sumObjects(first)); // {a: 2, b: 4}
console.log(sumObjects(first, third)); // {a: 2, b: 4, d: -5}
console.log(sumObjects(first, second, third)); // {a: 4, b: 14, d: -5}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```